# Connect to Oracle using OLEDB with windows authentication

Tags: oracle, database-connection, oledb, sqlplus, integrated-security

I have an Active Directory account "Contoso\SomeWinAccount" which I need to use for connecting to Oracle database. When I run a command prompt as a user Contoso\SomeWinAccount, I can successfully connect to Oracle like this:

```
sqlplus.exe [OracleUserName]@myTnsName
```

`SELECT user FROM dual;` returns OracleUserName. This works fine and this is exactly what I need.

The problem is, I need to achieve the same using PowerShell and OLEDB. With this connection string I can connect, but `SELECT user FROM dual` returns SomeWinAccount:

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;User Id=/;Data Source=myTnsName;OSAutent=1;
```

What do I need to change in order to be able to act as OracleUserName when connected? Is it even possible with OLEDB provider?

Version: Oracle 12.2

Comment: Try `User Id=OracleUserName;`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks, actually I did. I can connect successfully  with this, but `SELECT user FROM dual;` still returns SomeWinAccount.

Comment: With this connection string it works fine: `Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;User Id=[OracleUserName];Data Source=myTnsName;OSAutent=1;`

Comment: the square brackets are necessary, it does not work without them